# Can I use a PUT request when required fields aren't filled in?

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.4

I'm trying to run about 10,000 put requests to update pricing via the API. A lot of the products have fields that are required, but aren't filled in.

Everything works when I update the pricing with a CSV, but I get an error when I try to update with the API.

Is there a way to PUT the data even with attributes mission?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "message": "The \"Model\" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again."

Comment: I solved it for now by finding all user created attributes that are required and changing the requirement to zero before the script runs, and setting them back to 1 afterwards